# Invalid relative paths in asp.net web app when hosting it on azure vm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I am developing a simple website that will display some tables with data from a json file. Using Asp.Net 8.0 with Visual Studio 2022(win10-64bit) and host on azure vm(ubuntu22-64bit).

Everything works perfectly fine when running the project on my machine and accessing the website on localhost however when I transfer the files to the VM and host the web app using docker I am greeted with this:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-66a8933c7c1805a80e910eba86d0bbd6-4abcad38c4232fd0-00

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
```

Followed by my footer which makes me believe the problem lies in the Index.cshtml:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="~/promo-video.svg" height="16px" width="16px"> </object>
```

I've been searching for the solution for days now and what I found suggests that I need to use Server.MapPath in order to resolve relative directories between different machines. I can't find this library anywhere to reference it in my project.

I tried using full paths as well as referencing Server.MapPath.

Comment: I suggest you need firstly make sure the line caused the issue, for example, you could set the application from production to development environment to see the details information or remove that line to see if application is working well or not.